# Eclipse plugin : remove library from bin.includes and force the plugin to depend on it during instalation

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I've a library on which my plugin depends. its been added in the lib directory under the plugin project and added to bin.dir to be shipped with the plugin.

Is there a way to remove it not to be shipped with the plugin and force eclipse to search for it during installation ?

Comment: Your goal is to download the library dependency from the web, or for it to be optional (i.e. present in some installations and not in others)?

Comment: to be mandatory and downloaded from the web

Comment: How are you shipping your plugin? Is it part of a feature in a p2 repository?

Comment: Yes it is in a feature project

Answer (score 0):

First create a plug-in for your library through the [`Plug-in from Existing JAR Archives`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/project_wizards/plugin_from_archives.htm) wizard.

Add the new plug-in as a dependency to your plug-in.

During provisioning operations your plug-in won't be installed without it's dependency.
Trying to install your plug-in to an Eclipse installation that does not already contain the library plug-in will fail with an error.

However, this is not usual in the Eclipse world.

Ideally, you should ship both plug-ins as part of a [feature](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/concepts/feature.htm).

> A Feature is used to package a group of plug-ins together into a
>   single installable and updatable unit.